# Recorrer valores de cada fila de una table jquery

Tags: jquery

quisiera obtener los valores de los campos de una fila mediante jquery; les dejo mi codigo

**html:**

```
<table id="tabla">
 <tr>
  <td><select name="plato">
   <option value="0">SELECCIONAR</option>
   <option value="1">PLATO 1</option>
   <option value="2">PLATO 2</option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td><input name="cantidad"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button btn-action="add-fila">Agregar Fila</button>
<button btn-action="getPedido">
```

lo que deseo es que al dar click en `btn-action="getPedido"` me recorra todos los `<tr>` creados estatica y dinamicamente, y no contar a los `tr` que tengan el `<select name='plato'>` con valor vacio o valor 0

Notas:

- El boton `btn-action="add-fila"` añade un `<tr>` al final de la `tabla` donde abra plato y cantidad (igual a los anteriores `tr`)
- intente con este codigo pero no obtuve ningun resultado:

```
$("#tbl_registrar_pedido").children("tr").find("select").each(function() {
          valores += $(this).val() + "\n";
          alert(1);
        });
```

Comment: $("#tabla").children("tr").find("select").each(function() {
          valores += $(this).val() + "\n";
          alert(1);
        });
pero no sirve

Answer (score 0):

Lo obtienes obteniendo primero los selects, y luego buscas los que tienen valor.

```js
$(function(){
  

  $('button[btn-action="getPedido"]').on('click', function(){
    var lsSelects = $('#tabla').find('select[name="plato"]');
    var lsContienenValor = [];
    
    $.each(lsSelects, function(index, item){
      if($(item).val() != "0"){
        lsContienenValor.push(item);
      }
    });
    
    $.each(lsContienenValor, function(index, item){
      console.log('tr', $(item).parent().parent());
    });
    
    
  });
  
  $('button[btn-action="add-fila"]').on('click', function(){
    var ucControl = $(`
      <tr>
        <td><select name="plato">
         <option value="0">SELECCIONAR</option>
         <option value="1">PLATO 1</option>
         <option value="2">PLATO 2</option>
         </select>
        </td>
        <td><input name="cantidad"></td>
      </tr>
    `);
    
    ucControl.appendTo('#tabla');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
</table>
<button btn-action="add-fila">Agregar Fila</button>
<button btn-action="getPedido">getPedido</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aca va un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //EVENTO CLICK BOTON.
    $("button[btn-action=\"getPedido\"]").on("click", function () {
        //VARIABLE DONDE SE CONCATENA PEDIDOS.
        var valores = "";
        //RECORRO LOS TR Y SELECT CON ATRIBUTO NAME.
        $("#tabla").find("tr").find("select[name='plato']").each(function () {
             var comidaID = $(this).val();
             //VERIFICAR QUE NO SEA 0 EL VALOR DEL SELECT
            if (comidaID !== "0") {
                //OBTENGO EL NOMBRE DEL SELECT SELECCIONAO.
                var comidaNombre = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
                //OBTENGO LA CANTIDAD QUE ESTA EN OTRA POSICION DEL NODO DOM.
                var cantidad = $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").find("input:eq(0)").val();
                //SI ESTA VACIO O CANTIDAD 0 DEJO 1.
                if (cantidad==="" || cantidad==="0"){
                    cantidad=1;
                }
                //CONCATENO A LA VARIABLE
                valores += "ComidaID:" +  comidaID + " - Comida:" + comidaNombre + " - Cantidad: " + cantidad + "\n";
            }
        });
        //MUESTRO EL RESULTADO.
        console.log(valores);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
                <tr>
                    <td><select name="plato" >
                            <option value="0">SELECCIONAR</option>
                            <option value="1">PLATO 1</option>
                            <option value="2">PLATO 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input name="cantidad"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><select name="plato" >
                            <option value="0">SELECCIONAR</option>
                            <option value="1">PLATO 1</option>
                            <option value="2">PLATO 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input name="cantidad"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><select name="plato" >
                            <option value="0">SELECCIONAR</option>
                            <option value="1">PLATO 1</option>
                            <option value="2">PLATO 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input name="cantidad"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button btn-action="add-fila">Agregar Fila</button>
            <button btn-action="getPedido">Get pedido</button>
```